# Raspberry Pi SIM card, tethering and internet possibilities on the run

Tags: raspbian, networking, hardware, wireless

An idea just came to me, which I am not sure if any of you has done it. And if so, hopefully someone could share with me how I could achieve this.

I was wondering if I could set up a Raspberry Pi using either a micro SIM card that provide internet access like the ones they put in laptops?

In addition, if that's possible, does anyone know if it would be possible as well to make the Raspberry Pi to share internet connection like tethering? This way, let say, my cell phone can use the internet connection through it. You might say, why, because most of the cell phone can connect to intent par se. Again, I am just curious.

So, all in all, I was hoping to know if it is  possible at all for a Raspberry Pi to connect to the internet not being at home (i.e. via a cell SIM card, etc) and share the intent with other wireless gadgets on the run.

Thanks.

Comment: RPi has absolutely no connector that fits your SIM card, otherwise it's a very great idea.

Comment: Use USB GSM dongle. I tried Huawei E1xx model once a time. http://consumer.huawei.com/en/mobile-broadband/data-card/index.htm